# Как остановить автоперемотку слайдов на последнем слайде slick js?

Tags: javascript, slick.js

Использую известный slick js, с такими настройками:

```js
$('.storys_slider').slick({
    dots:true,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplaySpeed: 5000,
    infinite: false
  });
```

На последнем слайде автоперемотка должна остановиться, но слайды начинают листаться в обратном порядке. Потом снова доходят до 1 слайда и снова в обратном порядке. И так бесконечно. Как это решается? Уже битый час пытаюсь найти решение, но всё тщетно( Буду крайне признателен за помощь

Answer (score 0):

Используйте коллбэк `beforeChange` и проверяйте является ли текущий слайд последним. Если да - отключайте автоперемотку

```js
$('.storys_slider').slick({
   dots:true,
   autoplay: true,
   autoplaySpeed: 5000,
   infinite: false
});

$('.storys_slider').on('beforeChange', function(e, slick, current, next){
   if (next === slick.slideCount-1){
      slick.autoPlay = false;
   }
});
```